# Loose connection when attaching an Arduino shield with header pins

Tags: soldering, pins, arduino

I am adding this Spectrum Analyzer shield to my Mega:
[image: Sparkfun Spectrum Analyzer]

Using these header pins:
[image: header pins]

The square pegs of the header pins are worringly loose inside the holes of the shield.
I know soldering is an option, but I have no experience with it and worry that I may bridge a connection between two adjacent pins with a little runaway solder.

Any ideas for non-soldering fixes?

Comment: Those are *designed* to be soldered. Find a practice board if you don't trust yourself yet.

Comment: Look on soldering as a basic life skill : learning and practice won't be wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only alternative to soldering is a non soldering solution, like press fit headers. Unfortunately, this comes at the expense of A) Stacking, B) Reuse, as press fit headers pretty much destroy the holes, and C) cost.

Soldering is the only practical solution. Those are 0.1" or 2.54 mm standard through-hole sized spaced holes. Solder bridges are pretty difficult to do at that size unless you really overdo the solder. And even if you do, fixing it only requires some desoldering braid or a desoldering bulb.Its not like the ultra fine pitch you see in SMD parts. You have to intentionally screw up to cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen non-solder headers for sale on some sites (eg https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10527) but I've never used them.

I've only soldered a two shields and one custom project ever. It's not that difficult if you're careful. Just have a look for a basic soldering guide or two on YouTube.